# Can i give ftp access to default user (ubuntu in my case)?

Tags: ubuntu, amazon-ec2, ftp

By default in amazon ec2 ubuntu instances, a "ubuntu" user is created without password (only with amazon security passkeys).

If i create a password to this user, will it destroy my instance ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think will destroy the instance , but i would be careful sharing the password with 3rd parties. For example ftp would allow them to access the authorized keys for ssh, they could add their own, then ssh in. And because 'ubuntu' has sudo rights, they could gain total control.

Answer (score 0):

I wouldn't give any user with sudo access FTP privileges at all, and any user capable of FTP should have shell login disabled (/bin/nologin).

You really should use SFTP with your private key for the best security. It won't harm your instance in any way, though.